# Is there a word describing someone who is ignorant in the ways of Science?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives

I am not sure if dogmatic or doctrinaire covers it, but I am looking for a word to describe someone (like a politician) who is willfully unknowing of how the scientific method works and what science can and cannot accomplish.

I am looking for a descriptive word, and not a derogatory term like "ignoramus". And somehow it has to convey the idea that their ignorance applies to scientific domain only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are "looking for a *world*" where this happens, I would suggest Earth.

If you are looking for a *word*, I can't help you but I can offer:

- scientifically illiterate
- unscientific
- non-analytic
- non-evidence based

Of a more anti-technology (rather than anti-science) turn, we have:
 - Luddite
 - technophobe

Answer (score 1):

If we go from **[antiscience](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Anti-science)** ideology, we can call them **antiscientist**. (or anti-scientist). "**Antiscience proponent**" is another phrase that is used in some of the sources.

> The term "anti-science" refers to persons or organizations that promote their ideology over scientifically-verified evidence, **either by denying said evidence and/or inventing their own.**
>
> This modern usage of the term should not be confused with the anti-science movement in the 1960s and 1970s, which was largely concerned with the possible dehumanizing aspects of uncontrolled scientific and technological advancement.
>
> While this skepticism of unchecked change meets the classic dictionary definition of conservatism, it falls far short of the **anti-intellectual thrust of modern political conservatism.**
>
> The term can also describe policy decisions which, for political reasons, **ignore the advice of scientists** asked to inform said policy.

---

If you are looking for an adjective that conveys ignorance, that would be [**unscientific**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unscientific):

> *adj* **2.** ignorant of science

---

> *If that any wight ween a thing to be otherwise than it is, it is not only unscience, but it is deceivable opinion. --Chaucer.*

Comment: I don't think anti- describes ignorance. To the layman it sounds like hostile towars science, whereas ignorance should just represent lack of understanding.

Comment: @ja72: The question is talking about an intentional ignorance and political behavior also. So it is beyond ignorance or illiteracy.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on exactly what you are trying to convey, **empiricist** may fit. However, the term can mean somewhat contradictory things.

On one hand, *[empiricism](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/empiricist)* means

> experimental method; search for knowledge by observation and experiment

This is a critical aspect of the scientific method. While other factors also come into play in a scientific approach, many respected scientists would happily define themselves as *empiricists*.

However, *empiricism* also means

> a disregarding of scientific methods and relying solely on experience

When the experiences that form the basis of an *empiricist's* viewpoint are limited to those that come his way by chance, the conclusions are most unscientific.

Finally, *empiricism* can also mean

> (philosophy) the theory that sense experience is the only source of knowledge

This truly flies in the face of modern science and the scientific method.

[Note that all three definitions are from the same dictionary, Collins.]

[And, yes, I know that I counted on three hands.]